# PCM to dbspl conversion in esp-idf

Tags: esp32, sound, i2s, pcm, pdm

using i2s interface of esp32-wroom-32 i am getting PCM data from PDM micro-phone. how can i measure acoustic sound pressure level?

below is datasheet sheet of micro-phone.
from 16-bit array how can i measure decibels what is correct mathematical formula

i am really struck here. How i can convert this 2048 int16_t PCM array to DBSPL what steps are involve in this conversion.

[image: Micro phone datasheet]

Comment: The data sheet says 94 dB SPL is equal to -26 dB FS. Can you be more specific what the problem is? Will the other almost identical questions answer your questions?

Comment: data is stored in int16_t 2048 long array. from this data how can i measure dbspl what is correct formula i am getting wrong values 

double sample = (((double)r_buf[i]/32768.0));
double rms = sqrt(sample);
double decibel = 20 * log10(rms); 
in these steps what i am doing wrong

Comment: How do you know those values are wrong? Taking an RMS requires squaring somewhere before taking the root. And I have no idea if you take square root of each sample or for the block of 2048 samples somehow.

Comment: Assuming half your samples are positive and half are negative the sqrt() is going to fail for the negative ones.    As JustMe says you need to square, at a minimum.  Then there is an offset to apply to map it back to the reference (1kHz at 94dbspl).

Comment: after calculating the rms how can i map it back to reference what is correct mathematical formula behind it please help @RobinIddon

Comment: I suppose the question is, why are you computing RMS at all?   Are you trying to get a dBspl figure for each and every sample, or are you trying to get one dBspl figure for a batch of consecutive samples?  You need to describe your problem more accurately.

Comment: i am trying to do it with both calculate dbspl for a single 16 bit pcm and for an array of n elements but no luck at all cloud not figure out how to do that